# сложить числа js

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица при нажатие на кнопку меняются числа.

```
 <td class="text-right">
 <span class="sum<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?> total">
 <?php echo $product['total']; ?></span>
 </td>
```

так я получаю все числа в таблице

```
  var sum = $('.total').text();

    var newSum = sum.replace(/[$]/gi, '');

    console.log(newSum);
 7.70 17.00 17.00 9.50
```

А как их можно сложить между собой ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "7.70 17.00 17.00 9.50 ";
var result = str.split(" ").reduce((res, item) => +item + res, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getSum(str) {

  var arr = str.split(/\s+/);
  var arrSum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrSum += parseFloat(arr[i], 10);
  }
  return arrSum;

}
console.log(getSum("7.70 17.00  17.00 9.50"));
```

Comment: а почему минус - что не так в данном решении?

Comment: видимо, то же самое, что и в моем :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно получить сумму всех чисел не зависимо от текста:

```js
function sum (text) {
  let match
  return !!(match = text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)) ?
    match.reduce((sum, curr) => +sum + +curr)
  : 0
}

console.log(sum('7.70 17.00 17.00 9.50 '))
console.log(sum('10, 12, 40'))
console.log(sum('1 12 510'))
console.log(sum('LLLLLLLL'))
console.log(sum('<tag first="30" second="-10" />'))
console.log(sum('a: 5 и b: -5'))
```